# Using unmanaged thread-unsafe library in WCF service hosted in IIS

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, thread-safety, unmanaged

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS which calls into thread-unsafe unmanaged library.

I need to somehow setup IIS so that it keeps a pool of processes and assigns only one request per process.

How can I do it?

**Explanation of the nature of thread unsafety**:
Unmanaged library contains process-wide shared static array which is zeroed at the start of the operation, then slowly (30s-3m) populated with results during the operation, then final result is returned to me. Calls are not CPU-intensive, data is collected from external sources.
It is safe to make sequential calls but any parallel calls cause data corruption in the array and both calls return wrong results.
I have no control over this library.

I need to be able to process 30-100 requests in parallel.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about why your unmanaged library is unsafe?  If it's because of memory and the state of an object, then you wouldn't necessarily need multiple processes running.  You could get by with each session or call having it's own instance of the service and therefore separate instances of the unmanaged object.

Comment: This shared static array is *per thread* or *per process*?

Comment: @AllonGuralnek per process

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a single per-process resource, you'll need to spin up processes manually, as I'm not aware of any way to do this automatically. You can still use WCF to perform inter-process communication and to have a single public-facing entry point for all processes.

You'd need one supervisor service that will accept the request, spin up a worker process, send it the data and wait for it to complete then receive the data and forward it to the original requester. Each worker process can host a WCF server by using the [`ServiceHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx) class (very simple to use). You can either have the worker process terminate when it returns the result or you can perform your own pooling. If you want to pool, simply have two methods on the worker contract: `DoWork` and `Shutdown`. Call the DoWork of each worker serially, or you can have WCF itself block concurrent requests by applying the following attribute to the worker service class:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,
                 ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
```

This will ensure that any attempt to run two parallel operation on a single worker process will block and queue the request up, so you can simple call all your worker threads in a round-robin fashion to handle and queue-up peak loads that exceed your processing capacity.

Your supervisor will have a simple client-facing contract that simply dishes out the work to a worker process. If you're pooling the workers, you can shut some of them down when the load decreases and they're no longer needed (if that's desirable). The supervisor can use WCF's asynchronous pattern to use practically no resources (since it doesn't really do any work) instead of each request blocking and tying up a thread. For WCF async I'd suggest using .NET 4.5 as that is much easier to implement (simply return a `Task<T>`) compared to jumping the async hoops required by WCF in .NET 4.0 and below.

The bottom line is that due to your odd constraint you'll have to do a bit of leg work to achieve your desired goal. Still, most of the plumbing can still be handled by WCF.

Comment: My service is hosted in IIS. IIS can spin processes (so called web forest). Is there any way to utilise IIS facilities to help achieving what you've described?

Comment: @KonstantinSpirin: I don't know about IIS itself but from the WCF side there isn't a way to control processes, only threads (AFAIK). IIS may have the capability you describe, but I'm not an IIS expert, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use[ServiceThrotttlingBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms735114%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to configure the pool of processes, and [Concurrency Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.concurrencymode.aspx) to specify whether a service class supports single-threaded or multi-threaded modes of operation.

[Instance Context Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontextmode.aspx) specifies the number of service instances available for handling calls that are contained in incoming messages.

For your case,
1. `ConcurrencyMode` should be `ConcurrencyMode.Single` or `ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant`.
2. `InstanceContextMode` should be `PerCall` or `PerSession`.

[Sessions, Instancing, and Concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193.aspx)

[WCF Concurrency (Single, Multiple, and Reentrant) and Throttling](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/89858/WCF-Concurrency-Single-Multiple-and-Reentrant-and)

Comment: Will process multiple requests in parallel in different processes?

Comment: Each process is different. Setting InstanceContextMode to PerCall or PerSession will process multiple requests by multiple service objects within same Process.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not allowed to have several parallel requests running in the same process (see my question update for clarifications).